# Is there any pySPark function simmilar to isin but returns bool?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I trying to write:

```
F.when(
    F.col("COL1").isin("VAL1", "VAL2") & (F.col("COL2") == 1),
    F.col("SOMECOL")
)
```

I have an error

```
AnalysisException("cannot resolve '('VAL1' AND (COL2 = 1))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '('VAL1' AND (COL2.
```

How can I replace isin method so that it will work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `F.array_contains`:

```py
F.when(
    F.array_contains(F.array("VAL1", "VAL2"), F.col("COL1")) & (F.col("COL2") == 1),
    F.col("SOMECOL")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, the easiest solution is wrap my functions in parentheses